# asp:FileUpload multiple does not react if too many files are selected

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have the following upload control in my page:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" accept="image/*" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
```

This works fine as long as not too many images are selected. Actually, 6 images or more (each around 800kb) do not work. The upload starts and after a minute or so, a message appears that the page cannot be shown (Chrome shows constantly the message "Uploaded (1%)..." in the bottom left).

The method uploadFile_Click on server side is never executed, so somehow, the upload does not complete.

Comment: Have you checked the `web.config` for limits? `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength`?

Comment: That was the trick, I added the maxRequestLength attribute with a large enough number and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the upload-file size is set to 4MB [Refer to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx)

You can add the following in the `web.config`

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <!-- Upto 1024MB (1GB) -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
     <!-- Upto 1024MB (1GB) -->
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

**Please Note:** `maxAllowedContentLength` is measured in bytes and `maximumRequestLength` is measured in kilobytes when settings these values you'll need to adjust them accordingly if you plan on handling larger files

Updating the `maxRequestLength` property will be the easiest method of handling this